# CentOS 7 autofs wildcard mount not working

Tags: nfs, openldap, centos7, cifs, autofs

I've got a couple of CentOS 7 client machines authenticating against OpenLDAP right now.  The next step is to get autofs working.  Which I have, but my map loads all users at once.  I'd like to avoid this.  Assume I have two users

```
user1
user2
```

They both have a NFS share and I want to map them using autofs.

```
/home -fstype=nfs,rw domain.com:/homes
```

Works, but I get everyone.  I thought that I could use variables or wildcards to achieve this.  So I attempted the following map

```
/home/${USER} -fstype=nfs,rw  domain.com:/homes/${USER}
/home/${USER}/Music -fstype=nfs,rw  domain.com:/homes/${USER}/&
```

But it would appear that my variables aren't liked by CentOS.  I've tried

```
/home/${USER} -fstype=nfs,rw  domain.com:/homes/${USER}
/home/$USER -fstype=nfs,rw  domain.com:/homes/$USER
/home/* -fstype=nfs,rw  domain.com:/homes
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Thank you!

Edited for logs

```
Dec  8 22:22:13 workstation automount[1897]: setautomntent: lookup(sss): setautomntent: No such file or directory
Dec  8 22:22:13 workstation automount[1897]: do_mount_autofs_direct: failed to create mount directory /home/${USER}
```

Comment: Use something like '*       fileserver.example.com:/export/home/&'

Answer (score 1):

From the autofs man page:

```
Map Key Substitution

An & character in the location is expanded to the value of the key field that matched the line (which probably only makes sense together with a wildcard key).

Wildcard Key

A map key of * denotes a wild-card entry. This entry is consulted if the specified key does not exist in the map. A typical wild-card entry looks like this:
*    server:/export/home/&
The special character '&' will be replaced by the provided key. So, in the example above, a lookup for the key 'foo' would yield a mount of server:/export/home/foo.
```

Am typing from my phone so apologies for the formatting.